# web scraping can't get data of all links in page at same time

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

From someday I am trying to crawl all vessel data from [vesselfinder](https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels) with its description page, like from description page I want its information like vessel type, Imo number etc. in table form. I try different way to do this but still a lot of errors. First, I found that how I go through these links to its description page, how to get all these links from all pages, also how to get specific table data from its description page (which is still not complete but get some).
But today I try get the data from all links with its description pages at same time, it gives me a lot of error which make me so confused (by combining the code).
I attached my code, which is not good but to this point `#print(len(vessellist))` it work after that… errors..

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
}

baseurl = 'https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels'

vessellist = []
for x in range(1,6):
    response = requests.get(
        f'https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels?page={x}', 
        headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    contents = soup.find_all('td', class_='v2')

    for property in contents:
        for item in property.find_all('a', href=True):
            vessellist.append(baseurl + item['href'])

 
for link in vessellist:
      response = requests.get(link, headers=headers)

     soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
     table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'tparams')

     head = []
     for i in table.find_all('td', class_ = 'n3'):
         title = i.text
         head.append(title)

    values =[]
    for row in table.find_all('td', class_ = 'v3'):
        data = row.text
        values.append(data)

    df = pd.DataFrame(values)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - At first check your indentation and improve your question/code, please. Thanks

Comment: In this case, I can help you  using scrapy and specify what data items  do you need to scrape

Comment: Actually if you see on this page https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels, there is vessel information, I don't need this one (table ), i just need that web crawler automatically go through links vessel names have in this table , like first vessel name have link  https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels/PRELUDE-IMO-9648714-MMSI-503000101 and this page have vessel description in "Vessel Particulars" table . i want to save  these data of all vessel in csv format have table heading "IMO number", "Vessel Name", "Ship type", "Flag" and "Year of Built" like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two steps: get summary data (includes href).Next get detailled ones. Theses two steps are implemented in two functions. Here I get first 10 pages, 200 are available.

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests.api import head

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"}


def getSummaryData():
    data = []
    url = "https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels"
    for page in range(1, 10+1, 1): # only 200 first pages autorized ?
        print("Page : %d/10" % page)
        resp = rq.get(url + "?page=%s" % page, headers=headers)
        soup = bs(resp.content, "lxml")
        section = soup.find_all('section', {'class', 'listing'})[0]
        tbody = section.find_all('tbody')[0]
        trs = tbody.find_all('tr')
        for tr in trs:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            # column 1 data
            sub = tds[1].find('a')
            href = sub['href']
            divs = sub.find_all('div')
            country = divs[0]['title']
            sub_divs = divs[1].find_all('div')
            vessel_name = sub_divs[0].text
            vessel_type = sub_divs[1].text
            # column 2 data
            build_year = tds[2].text
            # column 3 data
            gt = tds[3].text
            # column 4 data
            dwt = tds[4].text
            # column 5 data
            size = tds[5].text
            # save data
            tr_data = {'country': country, 
                       'vessel_name': vessel_name,
                       'vessel_type': vessel_type,
                       'build_year': build_year,
                       'gt': gt,
                       'dwt': dwt,
                       'size': size,
                       'href': href}
            data.append(tr_data)
    return data

def getDetailledData(data):
    for (iel, el) in enumerate(data):
        print("%d/%d" % (iel+1, len(data)))
        url = "https://www.vesselfinder.com" + el['href']
        # make get call
        resp = rq.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = bs(resp.content, "lxml")
        
        # position and voyage data
        table = soup.find_all('table', {'class', 'aparams'})[0]
        trs = table.find_all('tr')
        labels = ["course_speed", "current_draught","navigation_status",
        "position_received", "IMO_MMSI", "callsign", "flag", "length_beam"]
        for (i, tr) in enumerate(trs):
            td = tr.find_all('td')[1]
            el.update({'%s' % labels[i]: td.text})

        # vessel particulars
        table = soup.find_all('table', {'class', 'tparams'})[0]
        trs = table.find_all('tr')
        labels = ["IMO_number", "vessel_name", "ship_type", "flag", 
        "homeport", "gross_tonnage", "summer_deadweight_t", 
        "length_overall_m", "beam_m", "draught_m", "year_of_built", 
        "builder", "place_of_built", "yard", "TEU", "crude", "grain", 
        "bale", "classification_society", "registered_owner", "manager"]

        for (i, tr) in enumerate(trs):
            td = tr.find_all('td')[1]
            el.update({'%s' % labels[i]: td.text})

        #break
    return data
```

Call theses functions :

```
data = getSummaryData() # href include
data = getDetailledData(data)
```

Don't rely on 'class' tag to target the data. Generally, you need to go throught table -> tbody and then get tds or trs to be sure that's the correct ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  Actually I am new to python that's why I use the simple way to crawl webpage. can you comments to the codes for me , some place i dont understand that how its work? what i want to crawl all pages on this site? how to save these data to csv?  i run this code it just show me empty result.   thanks again its will be really helpful for me.

Comment: This code is essentially about html DOM and python package BeautifulSoup. You should follow tutorial on both. Here python boils down to functions, loops and dictionaries.. so basics. Don't forget to call getSummaryData() and getDetailleData(data) functions as well :). Once you have data filled with data, search how to write list of dict to csv (another question)

Comment: I verify, data contains all data :)

Comment: ok i will try to study and understand all code. hope i got it thanks

Comment: Hello! I study your code and run it, which show result page number and number of links it go through.. if  I want the name links only to get information from "def getSummaryData()" and using these links get all description pages to collect all "# vessel particulars" table for all vessel and save it to csv file have table head : ["IMO_number", "vessel_name", "ship_type", "flag", 
        "homeport", "gross_tonnage", "summer_deadweight_t", 
        "length_overall_m", "beam_m", "draught_m", "year_of_built", 
        "builder", "place_of_built", "yard", "TEU", "crude", "grain", ....] ?

Comment: Hello!  I run the code when  increase number of page from 10 to 20 it give me some error:  227/400
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Usuario/PycharmProjects/datacrawling/main.py", line 77, in <module>
    print(getDetailledData(data))
  File "C:/Users/Usuario/PycharmProjects/datacrawling/main.py", line 70, in getDetailledData
    el.update({'%s' % labels[i]: td.text})
IndexError: list index out of range
 this is code line     for page in range(1, 20 + 1, 1):  # only 200 first pages autorized ?
        print("Page : %d/20" % page)